# RandomForest Model load error

Tags: json, hadoop, elasticsearch, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

My Spark program reads data from ElasticSearch(in JavaPairRDD> form). This JavaPairRDD is converted to JavaRDD using following inner class

```
static class Transformer implements
        Function<Tuple2<String, Map<String, Object>>, LabeledPoint> {

    @Override
    public LabeledPoint call(Tuple2<String, Map<String, Object>> arg0)
            throws Exception {
        HashingTF tf = new HashingTF();
        Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) arg0._2();

        // get values from Map
        Set<String> keys = map.keySet();
        List<Object> valuesList = new ArrayList<Object>();
        for (Iterator<String> i = keys.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            String key = (String) i.next();
            Object value = (Object) map.get(key);
            valuesList.add(value);
        }
        return new LabeledPoint(1d, tf.transform(valuesList));
    }
}
```

Using JavaRDD data RandomForest Model is generated and saved to the specific location on the same machine. Model gets saved successfully.

But while loading the model I am getting following exception,

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) at
>   org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293) at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.json4s.package$MappingException: Did not find value which can be
>   converted into java.lang.String at
>   org.json4s.reflect.package$.fail(package.scala:96) at
>   org.json4s.Extraction$.convert(Extraction.scala:554) at
>   org.json4s.Extraction$.extract(Extraction.scala:331) at
>   org.json4s.Extraction$.extract(Extraction.scala:42) at
>   org.json4s.ExtractableJsonAstNode.extract(ExtractableJsonAstNode.scala:21)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.model.DecisionTreeModel$.load(DecisionTreeModel.scala:326)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.model.DecisionTreeModel.load(DecisionTreeModel.scala)
>   at
>   co.nttd.integration.SparkESIntegration.main(SparkESIntegration.java:96)

To save model wrote following code

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Map<String, Object>> esRDD = JavaEsSpark
            .esRDD(javaSparkContext);
    // Transform data in JavaRDD<LabeledPoint>
    JavaRDD<LabeledPoint> data = esRDD.map(new Transformer());

    final RandomForestModel model = RandomForest.trainClassifier(
                inputTrainingData, numClasses, categoricalFeaturesInfo, numTrees,
                featureSubsetStrategy, impurity, maxDepth, maxBins, seed);

    model.save(JavaSparkContext.toSparkContext(jsc),
            "myPath");
```

To load model,
DecisionTreeModel model = DecisionTreeModel.load(sc.sc(), "file:///myPath");

Comment: It could be useful if show how you've saved and load the data.

Comment: I have updated my original query. Plz check.